# Lechem Mishneh by the Third Shabbos Meal

Tags: halacha, number, shabbat, meal-seudah, challah-shabbat-bread

Is one required to have Lechem Mishneh by the Third Shabbos Meal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One should have Lehem Mishneh by Seudas Shlishis and it is preferable to have Lehem Mishneh by **any** meal one has on Shabbos, even if he decides to have a fourth or fifth meal as well!

[Shulhan Aruch, Orach Haim, Siman 291, S'if 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=137)

Comment: Although it should be noted that the Rema there mentions that it is a widespread custom to use only one loaf of bread for Seudah Shlishis (and Taz ibid. :4 gives a rationale for this). Furthermore, in paragraph 5 the Mechaber mentions the various opinions that allow you to make Seudah Shlishis without bread at all (although he says that it is preferable not to rely on those opinions).

Comment: But the Rema himself says (right after bringing down the widespread custom) "however one should be stringent to take two". If one has a mimetic tradition to make it on only one, more power to him. Otherwise we do what the Rema tells us. (Or what one's posek tells him).

Comment: @Alex Also see Tosafos (*P'sachim* 101a, s.v. טעימו מידי), who indicates that even *minei targima* suffices.

Answer (score 5):

It says in [Hayom Yom (22 Adar Aleph)](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/6103/jewish/Hayom-Yom-22-Adar-I.htm) that the Rebbe Rashab ([5th Lubavitcher Rebbe, 1860-1920](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholom_Dovber_Schneersohn)) said that one one is not required to eat bread by the third meal because the third time it says "hayom" (the three meals are derived from the three "hayom" mentioned in chumash) it says "Hayom lo" which means today no.